# Vertica VerticaDayTimeInterval precision is stored wrongly

Tags: java, datetime, vertica

EDIT: Please point out if others are not seeing this issue, and I am doing something wrong.

I am trying to add rows to a table containing single VerticaDayTimeInterval column through the VerticaDayTimeInterval constructor.
The precision and fractional values are being wrongly printed and on retrieving precision for all 6 irrespective of what I gave earlier.

```
dayInt = new VerticaDayTimeInterval(10, 10, 01, 8, 2, 1, false) ; ((VerticaPreparedStatement) pstmt).setObject(1, dayInt) ; pstmt.addBatch() ; System.out.println(dayInt.toString());
dayInt = new VerticaDayTimeInterval(10, 10, 02, 7, 3, 2, false) ; ((VerticaPreparedStatement) pstmt).setObject(1, dayInt) ; pstmt.addBatch() ; System.out.println(dayInt.toString());
dayInt = new VerticaDayTimeInterval(10, 10, 03, 6, 43, 3, false) ; ((VerticaPreparedStatement) pstmt).setObject(1, dayInt) ; pstmt.addBatch() ; System.out.println(dayInt.toString());
```

table output

```
DayInt       
-------------------
10 10:03:49.000211
11 07:00:00.0002
9 09:09:05.000005
(3 rows)
```

retriving and printing rows with resultset.

```
for (int x=1 ; rs.next() ; ++x) {
    VerticaDayTimeInterval dti = (VerticaDayTimeInterval)(rs.getObject(1));
    System.out.println("vertica object tostring "+dti.toString()+" frac "+dti.getFraction()+" precision "+dti.getPrecision());
}
```

Output

```
vertica object tostring 10 10:03:49.211000 frac 211000 precision 6
vertica object tostring 11 07:00:00.200000 frac 200000 precision 6
vertica object tostring 9 09:09:05.500000 frac 500000 precision 6
```

My code is similar to
https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConnectingToHPVertica/ClientJDBC/UsingIntervalsWithJDBC.htm

Comment: It seems like something is removing the leading 0's. What it `rs.next` doing, how are you getting this data from the table? it is possible that the method may be the cause of your problems. Edit: Your code looks correct, I think the issue is caused in how you are retrieving the data from the table.

Comment: One other thought that may not help at all but it is worth a shot: Instead of using `(VerticaDayTimeInterval)(rs.getObject(1));` have you tried `rs.getObject(1, VerticaDayTimeInterval)`?

Comment: @sorifiend, unfortunately that cannot be done.

Comment: why are you using octal numbers as minute parameters? integers with leading zeros are treated as octal numbers. Perhaps the java class is confused at this point.

Comment: @JoshuaK, removing the leading 0 did not change the output, so octal conversion is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Precision is always a guideline for representation of data.
Data are always stored with a specific precision, which is the maximum precision supported by the driver (and the engine of course).
The precision that was used by the user to insert data is **not** stored in the database, as it is only useful when representing data.

Classic JDBC drivers support up to **nanoseconds (precision of 9 digits)** for *java.sql.Timestamp*.

Vertica JDBC driver supports up to **microseconds (precision of 6 digits)** for *VerticaDateTimeInteval*.

I don't know what is exactly your intent when you want to specify a precision of 1, 2 or 3 in your sample code, but, IMHO when you create a new *VerticaDateTimeInterval* object and you want to define a number of second fractions, you have 2 main options (that make sense):

- precision of 3, and the given fractions number would be in milliseconds
- precision of 6, and the given fractions number would be in microseconds.

With a precision of 1, the number of fractions is in tenths of second.
With a precision of 2, is in hundredths of second.
With a precision of 4, is in 1/10000s of second.
With a precision of 5, is in 1/100000s of second.

Accordingly, when the database returns your query result, then it should inform you that the integer content of the fractions field of the returned object has a precision of 6 (meaning this is a number of microseconds).

Comment: If you have access to vertica setup, could you confirm if this issue is seen or not seen for values 1-6 , which includes value of 3

Comment: Unfortunatelly not, I don't have access to vertica setup. All I wanted to say is that you don't need the fractions precision to be stored. And it's not stored.